# Laravel Jetstream Inertia non authorised route

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs

I have a fairly stock install of the Laravel, jetstream inertia js setup as shown here https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/installation.html using command `php artisan jetstream:install inertia --teams`

**I want to show the dashboard to non logged in users.** I am using a route without the `auth:sanctum', 'verified'` middleware, and trying to get the controller to set up the data that the inertia stack needs to fire up when the user IS logged in:

```
public function getPageDashboard(){
     return Inertia::render('Dashboard', [
        'user' => Auth::user()
     ]);
}
```

but I'm getting a lot of errors from the front end. "Error in render: "Error: Ziggy error: 'team' parameter is required for route 'teams.show'.""

Basically sanctum? jetstream? inertia? ziggy? sets up a lot of stuff somewhere in the middleware that I have not figured out.

Any ideas on my approach here?

Edit:
Here is the web route file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;

use App\Http\Controllers\ViewController;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/dashboard', [ViewController::class, 'getPageDashboard'])->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: Can you show your `routes/web.php` file. There you should define, that your `/dashboard` route should not use the `auth` middleware.

Comment: Yup,  edited above

Comment: I meant your complete `routes/web.php` file. We need to see the groups and middlewares applied to the route.

Comment: Edited once more

Answer (score 0):

Your request will fail to overwrite `user`, if you want to get the authenticated user in your view you can use `$page.props.user`